# I need to remove some spaces, dashes and date string in file names of csv files in a folder

Tags: powershell, automation

I have to run a quarterly report, using imported .csv files that we pull in from iAuditor.

All of these .csv files come in the following format:
`BOW 25-063 - - 2017-12-21.csv` (“BOW” is the building name, the five digit string is floor + room number)
or
`RMP 1108 - - 2017-12-21.csv`  (again, “RMP”=building / 1108= rm 08 on 11th floor)

I need to just trim this down to the building name, space, floor + room #
So: `BOW 25-063.csv`
or  `RMP 1108.csv`

I've got a short script that is doing most of the work, but is also taking out the space between the building and room number:

```
Get-ChildItem 'H:\csv Files\Testing' -filter *.csv | rename-item -NewName { $_.name.substring(0,$_.BaseName.length-15) + $_.Extension-replace " ","" }
```

There's over 100 rooms, therefore over 100 files that I need to rename, so that they can be imported into an .xlsx file for reporting.

They all need to follow the naming convention that we've established, so that they don't error out, and I don't have to manually adjust over 100 file names.

Looking for the tweak to shorten the name as needed, while leaving the one space in between the building and floor / room number.

Comment: Don't forget to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers) by checking the little check mark to the top left of my answer and make it go to green rather than gray and this will accept the answer giving me credit and letting others know too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an additional line of code utilizing the [insert](https://ss64.com/ps/insert.html) method to go back and perform the addition of the space after the 3rd character in the newly formatted file names after your first command runs which you are already using.

---

### Instructions

1. Run your original PowerShell first still

   > ```
   > Get-ChildItem 'H:\csv Files\Testing' -filter *.csv | 
   > rename-item -NewName { $_.name.substring(0,$_.BaseName.length-15) + $_.Extension-replace " ","" }
   > ```

   **Result**

   BOW25-063.csv

---

2. Run this PowerShell to add a space after the third character of the file name

   > ```
   > Get-ChildItem 'H:\csv Files\Testing' -filter *.csv | 
   > rename-item -NewName {$_.BaseName.insert(3,' ') + $_.Extension}
   > ```

   **Result**

   BOW 25-063.csv

---

### Further Resources

- [insert](https://ss64.com/ps/insert.html)

Comment: @Jeff Don't forget to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers) by checking the little check mark to the top left of my answer and make it go to green rather than gray and this will accept the answer giving me credit and letting others know too.